# Sending a Request To Every URL At Once Python

Tags: python, multithreading, function, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to create a script that allows me to send a GET request to every link in a text file at once. I am sure I could do this with threading but maybe you guys have a better suggestion. So far all it does is read each line one by one and send the request one by one.

```
import urllib2
def send(first,last):
    with open("urls.txt", 'r') as urls:        
        for url in urls:
            url = url.rstrip("\n")            
            print url                        
            urllib2.urlopen(url+"?f_name="+first+"&last_name="+last)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    first = raw_input("First Name: ")
    last = raw_input("Last Name: ")
    flood(first, last)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `requests`'s async. It's got its own package now, but you could use that. It runs of `gevent` and `greenlet`. https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests

Answer (score -1):

Never mind, threading is the best way to go, I figured it out.